# I Can't See My Units in Civilization Beyond Earth

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

Just started playing the game and for some reason I can't tell where my units are. The outline only shows if I click on the unit, but even then, I can't see the actual model. I basically have to guess where my units are located and then watch an empty blue hex move across the map.

My laptop is running on an Intel Core i5 processor with 6 GB of RAM. It's admittedly a bit slow, but I've never had any real issues playing Civ 5.

Comment: Computer specs and graphics settings might help us to locate the issue (as a rule of thumb).

Comment: Can you see the models of your satellites? If so, then you have the orbital layer on. Toggle it off and you should see your units. If this is your issue, I'll convert it into an answer.